# saving multiple objects to coredata, under a single name

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, swift3

I'm working on a project in swift 3.0 where I have a `UITableView` with multiple selection option (each row has a URL). Thus, on top of the `UITableView` use can enter a name in a UITextfield. My requirement is once these rows are been selected the data should get saved in `Coredata` under the typed name. As of now the data get saved as individual elements, so I have troubles with clustering data under its name. How could I achieve this ??. The method that I save and extract data as bellow.

Save

```
public static func savePlaylistDetails(audio:AudioDetails, playListName: String) {

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let newPlaylist = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: PlayList_DETAILS_ENTITY, into: context)


    newPlaylist.setValue(playListName, forKey:"playlistName");
    newPlaylist.setValue(audio.mediaId, forKey:"trackID");

    do{
        try context.save();
        print("Saved.....")
    }
    catch{
        print("There was an error")
    }
}
```

get the saved data

```
    public static func getPlayList() -> [PlayListDetails]?{
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate;
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext;

    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: PlayList_DETAILS_ENTITY)
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    do{
        let results = try context.fetch(request)
        if(results.count > 0 ){
            for result in results as! [NSManagedObject]{
                let playListDetails:PlayListDetails? = result as? PlayListDetails
                print("Title: \(playListDetails?.playlistName)")


            }
            return results as? [PlayListDetails]
        }else{
            print("No results")
        }

    }catch{
        print("Error in fetching items")
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Are you allowed to change the datatype of the field? If yes, then you can change the datatype to NSData then you can save array of strings in one field.

Comment: as in new to swift steps and a code snippet would much appreciate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a dictionary and save all the fields in dictionary with proper key. Then convert dict to data and save it in coreData
Saving..

```
let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: dictionary)
 let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let newPlaylist = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: PlayList_DETAILS_ENTITY, into: context)


    newPlaylist.setValue(data , forKey:"playlistData");
```

Retrieving

First get the data from the CoreData and then convert it to Dictionary again.

```
let unarchivedDictionary = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data)
```